# Install-Package Unity.WebForms

Tags: nuget

When I install this package for my VB solution I receive C# installation files when running the command, "Install-Package Unity.WebForms", from Package Manager Console with Visual Studio 2015.

How do I explicitly tell it to install Visual Basic files?

Answer (score 0):

*Unity.WebForms* currently only supports C# project types (because that is what I have worked on for the past 10+ years) and therefore only includes *.cs files. Also, until v3.3 and later NuGet didn't support deploying content files based on the project language-type; this had to be done through PowerShell scripts.

While it should be trivial to convert the C# code to VB code (using tools such as http://converter.telerik.com/), I haven't written any VB-based code in 15+ years and would want to make sure it is valid, well-formed, modern VB code. If you would like to contribute, you can fork the project ([Unity.WebForms Repo](https://bitbucket.org/KyleK/unity.webforms)), convert the C# code to VB, validate it with sample VB project, and submit a pull request for review. I would be happy to review it and release an updated NuGet package with multi-language support.

Comment: Interesting concept how the files must be converted into the language. How do I "fork" the project and attempt something that sounds, beyond trivial.

Comment: If these work like t4 templates I may have a shot :/